# Prob question - If the hats are both red, what is the probability that it was Factory A?

Tags: probability

Factory A makes: 40% red hats, 60% black hats
Factory B makes: 60% red hats, 40% black hats
Two hats are sampled at random from one of the factories, also selected at random.

If the hats are both red, what is the probability that it was Factory A?

I am struggling with this..
For Factory A, prob would be 2/5
For Factory B, prob would be 3/5
Am I right?

So then we ll have to add the prob of picking a factory randomly, so 1/2
Is it correct?

Then we have to add the prob that both hats will be red?
Any help, I am super lost :)

Comment: Ummm... could you explain the difference between "random probabilities" and "probabilities"?

Comment: Let $E$ be the event that both hats are red, $A$ the event that factory $A$ was chosen, and $B$ the event that factory $B$ was chosen. Then from Bayes Theorem $$P(A|E)=\frac{P(E|A)P(A)}{P(E|A)P(A)+P(E|B)P(B)}$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose each factory provides $100$ random samples of $2$ hats. Both provide the same number, so there is the same chance of selecting from each factory. From factory A there is $0.4$ chance a hat is red, so there is $0.16$ chance both hats are red, and so $16$ of the samples have both hats red. Similarly from factory B $36$ samples have both hats red.

We know that a sample of two red hats was chosen, so there were $16+36 = 52$ samples which could have been chosen. Conditional probability of 2 red from A given that there were 2 red is

Pr(factory A) = $\frac{16}{52} = \frac{4}{13}$.